# Creating a sys-admin web application?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis

I have some custom administrative tasks to perform on a server, but I want to be able to remotely administrate the server via a web-service / application. The tasks to be run on the server will require elevated access.

A simple answer would be to run an ASP.NET application as an administrator on the server, which will grant it all the privileges it needs to perform those administrative tasks. But running a web-app as an admin user doesn't come highly recommended (understandably). What then, are my options to provide a web application that can perform administrative tasks? My thoughts so far are:

1. Some sort of impersonation by ASP.NET.
2. A secondary process running on the server as admin (SYSTEM?) with named-pipe communication for the ASP.NET application to plug into.

What might the pros and cons of these two approaches be? Are there alternatives I haven't considered? To my thinking, ASP.NET impersonation might still be granting the web application far too much privilege, but creating a secondary process and maintaining all the appropriate interfaces is extra work that would ideally be avoided.

Comment: I know this might not solve your problem. But if this link helps then you might not have to write anything http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753798.aspx

Comment: I would go for ASP.NET impersonation actually

Comment: @GuruKara The admin tasks I'm opting for are proprietary. Some IIS automation, file moving, etc. And all on a "simple" user interface themed according to our application suite. So an off-the-shelf is out of the question (though a welcome suggestion). I'll look further into impersonation, but I'm left thinking that impersonating an admin user just makes the application every bit as un-safe as one running as admin anyway? The user visiting the web application isn't necessarily a sys-admin on the server, so... yeah.

Comment: Here are some of the suggestions. You need not use an Admin account, a "Power User" with specific minimal rights might also be enough for you. To make you app more secure run it over SSL and dont allow file uploads, and use Captcha for logins and important operations. These are just some of my suggestions.